# error 403 while building the app in AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, http-status-code-403, aws-serverless, aws-codecommit

I was trying to build a simple serverless web app in AWS. So, I put my static files in codecommit and tried to host it through AWS Amplify.The AWS builds the amplify.yml for us by default, but it is failing in the build stage. I understood that there is something wrong in amplify.yml and am not getting how to configure it.

amplify.yml :

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    build:
      commands: []
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

error I was shown:

```
2021-01-23T15:01:54.840Z [INFO]: # Cloning repository: https://git-codecommit.us-east- 
2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/wildrydes-site
2021-01-23T15:01:55.176Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'wildrydes-site'...
2021-01-23T15:02:02.660Z [INFO]: fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east- 
2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/wildrydes-site/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 1):

With the limited amount of information provided, the best I can offer is the issue is somewhere in your IAM privileges for your CodeCommit user.  AWS components generally need to have the appropriate Group, Role, and/or Policy to complete the action.

Put another way: CodeCommit is giving a 403 Forbidden error because whatever is attempting doing the cloning doesn't have the right permissions.  Give it the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the execution role that Amplify uses to run its builds by navigating to AWS Amplify > General (in the left-hand column).  Under the Settings section, you'll see a value for the "Service role" field.  It will look something like this: "arn:aws:iam:::role/service-role/AWSAmplifyExecutionRole-xxxx".

Once you find that, navigate to IAM > Roles and search for the service role that you just found (AWSAmplifyExecutionRole-xxxx) and click on it.  Then click "Attach policies".  Search for the "AWSCodeCommitReadOnly" policy and attach it to the role.

You should be able to clone your CodeCommit repository in your Amplify build now.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. I ran into this when I committed the code (while following the wildrydes tutorial) using a different IAM user than I was using in amplify "web" console. I had created a separate user to understand how I would segregate the users and permissions but this then led to this 403 error when I tried to deploy.